# Making more sense of the reshape() function

Tags: r, function, reshape

Consider the following dataset which is taken from this question: [Going from wide to long w/ coupled-columns: Is there a more R way to do this (i.e. - without using a for loop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53870876/going-from-wide-to-long-w-coupled-columns-is-there-a-more-r-way-to-do-this-i)

(`dput` at the end of the question)

```
   phrase wo1sp wo2sp wo3sp wo1sc wo2sc wo3sc
1   hello   dan  mark  todd    10     5     4
2   hello  mark   dan chris     8     9     4
3 goodbye  mark   dan   kev     2     4    10
4    what   kev   dan  mark     4     5     5
```

The goal is to reshape the data from wide to long taking into account that there is some pattern in the column names. The expected output is

```
    phrase time    sp sc
1    hello    1   dan 10
2    hello    1  mark  8
3  goodbye    1  mark  2
4     what    1   kev  4
5    hello    2  mark  5
6    hello    2   dan  9
7  goodbye    2   dan  4
8     what    2   dan  5
9    hello    3  todd  4
10   hello    3 chris  4
11 goodbye    3   kev 10
12    what    3  mark  5
```

@docendodiscimus provided a sound solution using `melt` from `data.table` but I'd like to use `reshape()` from the `stats` library for the sake of practice.

This function is certainly quite powerful but I almost always run into a problem with one of its arguments, so this time it's the `new.row.names` argument which I rarely used before.

I tried

```
reshape(
  dat,
  idvar = "phrase",
  varying = list(
    "sp" = grep("sp$", names(dat)), 
    "sc" = grep("sc$", names(dat))
  ),
  direction = "long", 
  v.names = c("sp", "sc") # name of cols in long format
)
```

This returns the error

> error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = paste(ids, times[i],  : 
>     duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>   non-unique value when setting 'row.names': ‘hello.1’

Reading the error message I found the 'solution' to be the `new.row.names` argument which I set to be `1:12`, see below. (I cheated here because I looked how many rows were returned by the `data.table` solution.)

My question is what would be the generic solution to this problem?

```
# works!
reshape(
  dat,
  idvar = "phrase",
  varying = list(
    "sp" = grep("sp$", names(dat)),
    "sc" = grep("sc$", names(dat))
  ),
  direction = "long", 
  v.names = c("sp", "sc"),
  new.row.names = 1:12 # 1:10000 would also work
)
```

**data**

```
dat <- structure(list(phrase = c("hello", "hello", "goodbye", "what"
), wo1sp = c("dan", "mark", "mark", "kev"), wo2sp = c("mark", 
"dan", "dan", "dan"), wo3sp = c("todd", "chris", "kev", "mark"
), wo1sc = c(10L, 8L, 2L, 4L), wo2sc = c(5L, 9L, 4L, 5L), wo3sc = c(4L, 
4L, 10L, 5L)), .Names = c("phrase", "wo1sp", "wo2sp", "wo3sp", 
"wo1sc", "wo2sc", "wo3sc"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: You need to add a variable that enables creation of a _unique_ id. Thus: `dat$id <- ave(dat$phrase, dat$phrase, FUN = seq_along)`. And then `idvar = c("phrase", "id")`. In the result, you can see the autogenerated rownames, now unique.

Comment: @Henrik Thanks for your comment. Creating another id column is a good hint. I thought it could work without it. Compared to the elegant data.table solution I found that a little cumbersome but if that's the way it is, please turn your comment into an answer and I'll be happy to accept.

Comment: Also, `reshape` works best when your variables are named in the pattern `sp1`,`sp2`... and `sc1`,`sc2`... etc (i.e. - name+NUMBER) - then you can do things like: `reshape(dat, idvar=c("phrase","id"), varying=2:7, sep="", direction="long")` and all the `varying` selections are done automatically.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks! Very useful comment as well. `reshape` and I are in this love-hate relationship and even after years we don't really know each other. But we try to keep going.

Comment: Or with hardcoded column positions in the two "groups": `reshape(dat, idvar = c("phrase", "id"), varying = list(sp = 2:4, sc = 5:7), direction = "long")`. Good'ol `reshape` rocks.

Comment: @Henrik "Good'ol `reshape` rocks" - yeah, that's what I am thinking too. But you know, all these arguments.

Comment: @markus I know, the arguments are the funniest part of it..;) But, I was so glad when I for once sake actually meant that it rocks ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41884029/1851712)) and was able to write "This is one of the (rare) instances where I believe good'ol `base::reshape` is cleaner [than `data.table::melt`]". Note the "rare"...